# Confirm multivariate Gaussian derivation by simulation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation, gaussian

I have a random process which is defined according to the model,
\begin{equation*}
    Y_i=Bf_i+W_i, \quad i=1,\ldots,N
\end{equation*}

Where $B,W_1,\ldots,W_N$ are i.i.d. with,
\begin{gather*}
    W_i\thicksim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_w^2)\\
    B\thicksim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_b^2)\\
\end{gather*}

The covariance matrix was determined to be,
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{C}=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    f_1^2\sigma_b^2+\sigma_w^2&f_1f_2\sigma_b^2&\cdots&f_1f_N\sigma_b^2\\
    f_1f_2\sigma_b^2&f_2^2\sigma_b^2+\sigma_w^2\\
    \vdots& &\ddots\\
    f_1f_N\sigma_b^2&\cdots& &f_N^2\sigma_b^2+\sigma_w^2
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

And therefore,
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{y}\thicksim\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{0}_N,\mathbf{f}\,\mathbf{f}^T\sigma_b^2+\mathbf{I}\,\sigma_{w}^2\right)   
\end{equation*}

I am now trying to show that the derivation is correct in Matlab.  I created $R=500$ realizations of a random signal.  Each realization took a value from $B$.  Each random signal was $N=100$ items long and the $i_{th}$ item within the random signal took a value from $W_i$.  For simplicity, I assumed that the vector $\mathbf{f}$ is a vector of ones.

If I autocorrelate each random signal and take the average, I get, ${\mathbf{f}\,\mathbf{f}^T\sigma_b^2+\sigma_{w}^2}$.  If I autocorrelate the values for a particular time-slice, $i$, across all realizations, I also get, ${\mathbf{f}\,\mathbf{f}^T\sigma_b^2+\sigma_{w}^2}$.

I am struggling however to simulate the covaraince terms.  For example, I thought that if I cross-correlate realization 1 with realization 2, then I would be able to get ${\mathbf{f}\,\mathbf{f}^T\sigma_b^2}$, but no success.

Comment: If you cross correlate, you are correlating different $B$ values, so the correlation should vanish. Think of it a as $Y^{j}_i= B_j f_i + W_i$

Comment: I understand.  There were actually two things wrong.  First was a bug in the code.  The seocond, more critically from your point: I was cross-correlating in the wrong diection.  If I cross-correlate for a given timeslice $i$ across all realizations with another time slice across all realizations, then the $W$'s are uncorrelated leaving me with just $\sigma_b^2$!